# mxml file erroring with `element type "components" must be followed by either attribute specifications`

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, blackberry-simulator

I am getting problem like

**Element type "components" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">"**

and my mxml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<components:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:components="spark.components.*" title="Home" creationComplete="srv.send()">
    
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:HTTPService id="srv" url="assets/employees.xml"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
    
    <s:List id="list" top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0"
            dataProvider="{srv.lastResult.list.employee}" 
            labelField="lastName"/>
</components:View>

<components:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:components="spark.components.*" title="Home" creationComplete="srv.send()">
```

this line gives me error like following line
**Element type "components" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">"**

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: @Cosma Colanicchia It was there; just not code formatted.   @raj you can format code by seecting it and pressing the '{}' button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things to consider:

1) You aren't using a Mobile Component project, and therefore do not have mobile components added to the library path.  [View](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/View.html) is a Mobile Component.  IF this is the case you can add it to the class path manually.

2) It is odd to define the spark components as a namespace separate of the default 's' namespace:.  This approach would be more common:

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Home" creationComplete="srv.send()">
</s:View>
```